# Unable open a project or project folder (by giving the path) into solution explorer with an vsix extension?

Tags: c#, vsix, vs-extensibility, extensibility, solution-explorer

I have a requirement to load a project in solution explorer by providing a path in the extension.

Suppose I have a *menu button* that opens a *window form* having a *text field* and a simple *button*. Now when we enter any path into the *text field* (assuming that an angular project exists on that path) and press the *button* (below the text field) then the project present on that path should be opened in solution explorer. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use `EnvDte.Solution.AddFromFile(path)`.